# Optimizing a python script that reads a csv file into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have written a python script to read a csv file into dataframe, sort depending on two rows (date and incident) then generate two columns X|Y from the data. The data comprises of different incidents which must be treated independently.
For each Incident ID; The column X is a list of Incidents, such that it grows from index = 0 till the index = len(listOfIncidents) and Y is just the ListOfIncident(index+1).
Assume this is the data (Useless columns omitted for clarity) ordered and ready to be split into X and Y
[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Nwq.png)
The Image below shows the X and Y result
[Sample Result Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys5Qf.png)

The CSV file is close to 500k row large, so First; I converted the date column into Unix(for easy sorting); then sorted the dataframe.
I created a function create_input_output to handle creating X and Y and appending to maindfObj

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime


# Function takes the computed IncidentActivity_Type and IncidentID as arguments
# Function Writes the IncidentActivity_Type into X and Y and create a CSV file using the IncidentID as file name
# Define the column Names
_ncols = ('X', 'Y')
# Define empty dataframe
maindfObj = pd.DataFrame([], columns=_ncols)
def create_input_output(xy, incident_id):
    global maindfObj
    # Define Empty List
    values = []
    xList = [];
    i = 0
    while i < len(xy):
        try:
            # Insert into X and Y so that X gets Index i and Y gets index i+1 etc
            xList = xy[0:i+1]
            values.append((xList, xy[i + 1]))
        except:
            xList = xy[0:i+1]
            # We have reached the end of list. Complete with NULL
            values.append((xList, "NULL"))
        i = i + 1
    # Write to dataframe
    subdfObj = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=_ncols)
    maindfObj = maindfObj.append(subdfObj)
    print("Appended "+ incident_id + ". New size: ") #print the size
    print(maindfObj.shape)
    # Create a filename
    #filename = incident_id + ".csv"
    # Write dataframe to file
    #subdfObj.to_csv(filename, sep=',')
    #print("Appended " + incident_id)

# Point to CSV file to be read. If file is in the same folder as python source just write filename
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/public/Incident_Activity.csv') as csv_file:
    # Read file. Possible delimiters are , ; and white space
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    # Create a new list to hold the read data rows
    _newarr = []
    # Create Column
    _columns = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        # First Row is the header
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
            _columns = row[0].split(',')
            _columns = list(_columns)
            # Appending new column UnixEquiv to hold computed date
            _columns.append('UnixEquiv')
        # Other Rows are the data
        else:
            # Split
            rowstr = row[0].split(',')
            # Convert to list
            rowstr = list(rowstr)
            # Convert dateTime to Unix Timestamp and append to last column
            rowstr.append(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(rowstr[1], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple()))
            # Append new row to _newarr
            _newarr.append(tuple(rowstr))
            line_count += 1
    # Convert List to dataframe
    dfObj = pd.DataFrame(_newarr, columns=_columns)
    # Sort dataframe by the IncidentID and Unix Timestamp calculated earlier
    dfObj = dfObj.sort_values(by=['Incident ID', 'UnixEquiv'])

    # Create temporary XY List
    _tempxy = []
    # Initialize active Incident ID to empty
    _activeIncident = ""
    # Routine separates the big data based on Incident ID
    for index, row in dfObj.iterrows():
        if row['Incident ID'] == _activeIncident or _activeIncident == "":
            # Incident ID has not changed
            _tempxy.append(row['IncidentActivity_Type'])
            _activeIncident = row['Incident ID']
        else:
            # Incident ID has changed.
            _activeIncident = row['Incident ID']
            # Let's write that to file before we start the next batch
            create_input_output(_tempxy, _activeIncident)
            # Clear old Incident ID
            _tempxy.clear()
            # Start new batch
            _tempxy.append(row['IncidentActivity_Type'])
    #Dataframe is ready here. Use
    print(maindfObj.shape) #print the size
```

The code works but takes too long to finish. I know people here who know better can help me optimize the script.

Comment: including screenshots breaks copying/pasting hence people will be less likely to help, it would be easy to replace the screenshots with CSV data and I'd encourage you to do so!

Comment: your code is also a long way from [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), most of the `print` statements seem redundant, there's lots of commented code (which should probably be removed), and lots of the comments are redundant, e.g. the line following "Convert List to dataframe" obviously does that, and should probably be removed.  `global` variables are generally discouraged, why not just return `subdfObj` and have the calling function `append` it?